# Centering a Gif

Tags: html, css, margin

Can anyone explain how this block of code works?

```
img{
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
```

I used this block of code to center a gif. My teacher said to try using align:center; but that had not worked either. I found the answer online but didn't understand it. I know a margin is used to create a space between two different blocks/backgrounds/borders. But what does the auto mean?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **display : block** style sets the element to take up it's full horizontal space on the page. The **margin: auto** sets the element horizontally within a container. It evenly distributes the space on left and right margin.